# How to make links click-able with position absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I finally got my logo at this page centered by using position absolute, but now my "Some links" aren't clickable. I've tried to add z-index to the menu_small div but it doesn't help.

```
<div id="menu">
            <div id="logo"><a class="logo" href="index.php"> THIS IS A SITE! </a></div>
            <div id="menu_small" href="xxxxx.php" style="margin-right: 10%; float: right;">Some link 1</div>
            <div id="menu_small" href="xxxx.php" style="margin-left: 10%; float: left;">Some link 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu{
width: 100%;
height: 90px;
float: left;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .82);
margin-right: 60px;
z-index: 1; }

#menu_small{
margin-top: 37px;
font-size: 18pt;
z-index:30; }

#logo{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
font-size: 38pt;
line-height: 90px;
text-align: center;
z-index: 2; }

.logo{
width: auto;
height: auto; }
```

Comment: Try to set position absolute for the div id:logo

Comment: Link works for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2yna7d8s/light/. BTW, `z-index` only works for positioned elements, so the rule in `#menu_small` won't do anything. Also, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Anton, div id:logo already has position absolute?
j08691, I can't click the "some link 1" or "some link 2" in the jsfiddle you linked.. Does it work for you? Thanks for the tip regarding z-index!

Answer (score 0):

They are not clickable, because they are not links (`<a>`), but divs with `href` attributes.

Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<div id="menu_small" style="margin-left: 10%; float: left;">
  <a href="xxxx.php">Some link 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I've changed it but it's still not clickable.

    <div id="menu_small" style="margin-left: 10%; float: left;"> <a href="xxxxx.php">Some link 2</a></div>

Comment: Because your "This is a site!" link is above the other links. In your CSS add `position:relative` to the `#menu_small` declaration.